# GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_CHECK syntax error on configure

Tags: gnu-make, gobject-introspection

On "./configure" of an open source project I get:

```
user agent OS = Linux
./configure: line 13957: syntax error near unexpected token 0.9.3'
./configure: line 13957: GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_CHECK(0.9.3)'
make: *** [config.status] Error 2
```

Ubuntu 12.04 package "gobject-introspection" and "libgirepository1.0-dev" are present.  Removing the GOBJECT_INTROSPECTION_CHECK line allows configure to complete, but the project fails a dependency later.

How can I get past this configure step cleanly?  Googling for this issue shows bugs filed against numerous OS projects for this same blocking issue, but the usual answer is "install gobject-introspection".

Comment: Did you run an `autogen.sh` or similar script to generate `configure`? Did you do that *before* you installed the `gobject-introspection` package? Does re-running whatever you ran let `configure` work if you try it again after?

Comment: That's it. I needed to run autogen a second time.  Post an answer and take credit @EtanReisner

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the OP discovered on his own he had to install the `gobject-introspection` package to get the m4 macros that were being used.

The error message has the raw macro in it, as `configure` scripts are generated from `configure.in`/`configure.ac` files via `m4`/etc the fact that the raw macro is in the output file indicates that the macro did not get translated at generation time.

The `gobject-introspection` m4 files were apparently installed after `autogen.sh` (or equivalent) was run to generate the `configure` script. Re-running the `autogen.sh` script should regenerate the `configure` script and run the macro correctly.

Comment: I don't know the details, but I had to install also libgirepository1.0-dev (According to [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/319568/i-cant-configure-rhythmbox-as-gobject-introspection-1-is-not-installed))